# Regex to match a string with 2 capital letters only

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a regex which will match a string only if the string consists of two capital letters.

I tried - `[A-Z]{2}, [A-Z]{2, 2} and [A-Z][A-Z]` but these only match the string 'CAS' while I am looking to match only if the string is two capital letters like 'CA'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use anchors:

```
^[A-Z]{2}$
```

`^` matches the beginning of the string, while `$` matches its end.

---

Note in your attempts, you used `[A-Z]{2, 2}` which should actually be `[A-Z]{2,2}` (without space) to mean the same thing as the others.

Comment: You beat me to it, Jerry. :) +1

Answer (score 6):

You need to add word boundaries,

```
\b[A-Z]{2}\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/11)

**Explanation:**

- `\b` Matches between a word character and a non-word character.
- `[A-Z]{2}` Matches exactly two capital letters.
- `\b` Matches between a word character and a non-word character.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
\b[A-Z]{2}\b
```

\b matches a word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Try =

```
^[A-Z][A-Z]$
```

Just added start and end points for the string.